# Bring the pageElements to front or back using apps script in Google Slides

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

The stacking order is determined by the order by which they are inserted into the slide. However, some of the page elements in slides remain hidden.

Is there a way to change the Order of objects in Google slides using apps script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this workaround? I have experienced the same situation with you. At that time, I have moved the element using this workaround. I think that there are several workarounds for this situation. So please think of this as one of them. The flow of this workaround is as follows.

#### Principle:

In Google Slides, for example, when new shape is created to a slide, it is added to the last element to `pageElements`. This means that the last element to `pageElements` is the most front. This is used for the workaround.

#### Flow:

1. Select shapes.

   - In this case, as a sample, the shapes which are brought to the front are selected by click.
2. Add the selected shapes to the page using `insertPageElement()`. These are added to the page as new elements.
3. Remove the selected shapes from `pageElements`.

By this, the selected shapes can be brought to the most front and back. When this flow is reflected to the script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
function move(page, spe) {
  var pe = page.getPageElements();
  spe.forEach(function(e) {
    page.insertPageElement(e);
  });
  pe.forEach(function(f, i) {
    if (spe.some(function(g) {return f.getObjectId() == g.getObjectId()})) {
      pe[i].remove();
    }
  });
}

// Bring to back
function back() {
  var slide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var selected = slide.getSelection();
  var page = selected.getCurrentPage();
  var pageElements = page.getPageElements();
  var selectedPageElements = selected.getPageElementRange().getPageElements();
  var noSelectedPageElements = pageElements.filter(function(e) {return !selectedPageElements.some(function(f) {return e.getObjectId() == f.getObjectId()})});
  move(page, noSelectedPageElements);
}

// Bring to front
function front() {
  var slide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var selected = slide.getSelection();
  var page = selected.getCurrentPage();
  var pageElements = page.getPageElements();
  var selectedPageElements = selected.getPageElementRange().getPageElements();
  move(page, selectedPageElements);
}
```

#### Result:

[image]

#### Note:

- When you use this script, at first, please select the shapes on a slide. Then run `front()` or `back()`. When `front()` is run, the selected shape is moved to the most front. When `back()` is run, it is moved to the most back.
- In this sample script, the selected shapes are brought to the most front and back. This is a simple sample script.

  - If you want to move the shapes every element, please modify the script.
- In this case, the moved elements are added as new elements. So the moved object IDs are updated.

#### References:

- [insertPageElement(pageElement)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#insertpageelementpageelement)
- [remove()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#remove)

If this answer was not what you want, I'm sorry.

### Updated at November 20, 2018:

[The Slides service was updated at Google's update at November 14, 2018, and several methods were added for achieving this issue.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/)

> The Slides service has been extended with the following new methods that let you control the Z-positioning of page elements in Slides.
>
> - bringForward()
> - bringToFront()
> - sendBackward()
> - sendToBack()