# google app slides pageElements bringToFront seem to be random

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I have read [Bring the pageElements to front or back using apps script in Google Slides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52630036/bring-the-pageelements-to-front-or-back-using-apps-script-in-google-slides)
I loaded dice images in order to my slide. Based on load order I expect:

```
0 - page title
1 - dice image 1
2 - dice image 2
3 - dice image 3
4 - dice image 4
5 - dice image 5
6 - dice image 6
7 - blank shape to cover dice - could also use lose a turn text box
```

The element displayed by bringToFront seemed random so I add several checkDice items to the menu.

```
  SlidesApp.getUi()
      .createMenu( 'Ask ?')
      .addItem('Roll', 'flipDice')
      .addItem('BE1','BE1')
      .addItem('BE2','BE2')
      .addItem('BE3','BE3')
      .addItem('BE4','BE4')
      .addSeparator()
      .addSubMenu(SlidesApp.getUi().createMenu('Check Dice')
          .addItem('Check 1', 'checkDice1')
          .addItem('Check 2', 'checkDice2')
          .addItem('Check 3', 'checkDice3')
          .addItem('Check 4', 'checkDice4')
          .addItem('Check 5', 'checkDice5')
          .addItem('Check 6', 'checkDice6'))
      .addToUi();
```

Here is the check dice code.

```
function checkDice1() {
  checkDice(1);
}

function checkDice2()  {
  checkDice(2);
}

function checkDice3()  {
  checkDice(3);
}

function checkDice4()  {
  checkDice(4);
}

function checkDice5()  {
  checkDice(5);
}

function checkDice6()  {
  checkDice(6);
}

function checkDice(showMe) {  
  const diceStackId = 'gaaaa1aa1ce_0_128';
  let presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  let presId = presentation.getId();
  let slide = presentation.getSlideById(diceStackId);
  let pageElements = slide.getPageElements(); 
  // let selectedPageElements = slide.getPageElementRange().getPageElements();
  
  console.log('numberof elements: ' , pageElements.length );  // numberof elements:  8
    /*  0 = title 
        1 = dice 1
        2 = dice 2
        3 = dice 3
        4 = dice 4
        5 = dice 5
        6 = dice 6
        7 = white to cover dice - could be lose turn 
    */
  // do this once
  switch (showMe)  {
    case 1 :
      console.log('Rolled 1 pageElements[1].getTitle = ',pageElements[1].getTitle() )
      pageElements[1].setTitle('Rolled-1')
      SlidesApp.getUi().alert('Show me dice number: ' + showMe + ' set title Rolled-1 ');   
      break;
    case 2  :
      console.log('Rolled 2 pageElements[2].getTitle = ',pageElements[2].getTitle() )
      pageElements[2].setTitle('Rolled-2')
      SlidesApp.getUi().alert('Show me dice number: ' + showMe + ' set title Rolled-2 ');   
      break;
    case 3  :
      console.log('Rolled 3 pageElements[3].getTitle = ',pageElements[3].getTitle() )
      pageElements[3].setTitle('Rolled-3')
      SlidesApp.getUi().alert('Show me dice number: ' + showMe + ' set title Rolled-3 ');  
      break;
    case 4  :
      console.log('Rolled 4 pageElements[4].getTitle = ',pageElements[4].getTitle() )
      pageElements[4].setTitle('Rolled-4')
      SlidesApp.getUi().alert('Show me dice number: ' + showMe + ' set title Rolled-4 ');  
      break;
    case 5  :
      console.log('Rolled 5 pageElements[5].getTitle = ',pageElements[5].getTitle() )
      pageElements[5].setTitle('Rolled-5')
      SlidesApp.getUi().alert('Show me dice number: ' + showMe + ' set title Rolled-5 ');  
      break;
    case 6  :
      console.log('Rolled 6 pageElements[6].getTitle = ',pageElements[6].getTitle() )
      pageElements[6].setTitle('Rolled-6')
      SlidesApp.getUi().alert('Show me dice number: ' + showMe + ' set title Rolled-6 ');  
      break;
  }
  SlidesApp.getUi().alert('Show me dice number: ' + showMe + ' element title: ' + pageElements[showMe].getTitle() );   
  pageElements[showMe].bringToFront();
}
```

The alerts show exactly what I expect but the dice image shown appears to be random. It changes! If I run check any number over and over I get different images! Am I misunderstanding pageElements[showMe]?  How can I get the desired image?

---

```
function onOpen() {
  console.log('In onOpen' );
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty(
    'sheetId', '1fmZCittj4ksstmhh8_t0O0csj8IDdwi9ohDDL5ZE7VA');
  const diceObj = {
    "1": "dice1", 
    "2": "dice2", 
    "3": "dice3", 
    "4": "dice4", 
    "5": "dice5", 
    "6": "dice6"
    };  
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty(
    'idDice', diceObj);
```

etc. then in the checkDice function:

```
function checkDice(showMe) {  
  const diceStackId = 'gaaafaff9f1_0_0';
  const idDice = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('idDice'); 
  let presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  let presId = presentation.getId();
  let slide = presentation.getSlideById(diceStackId);
  let pageElements = slide.getPageElements(); 
  SlidesApp.getUi().alert('Show me dice number: ' + showMe + ' element title: ' + pageElements[showMe].getTitle() );   
//  When a page element is moved to the front, the indexes are changed!
//  pageElements[showMe].bringToFront();
  const pageElement = pageElements.filter(e => e.getTitle() == idDice[showMe]);
  if (pageElement.length == 1) {
    pageElement[0].bringToFront();
  }
}
```

The dice is identified in the console.log but no change is made to the order of the images???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to move a page element to the front of the page by giving the value of `showMe`. `showMe` is from 1 to 6.

  - For example, when `3` is given as `showMe`, you want to move the page element with the title of `dice 3` to the front of the page.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `showMe` is used for the index of `pageElements`. In this case, when a page element is moved to the front, the indexes are changed. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.
- From the comment of your script, it seems that the title of page element has already been given like `1 = dice 1,2 = dice 2,3 = dice 3,,,`. I thought that this might be used for achieving your goal.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

In this modification, `checkDice()` is modified.

```
function checkDice(showMe) {
  const diceStackId = 'gaaaa1aa1ce_0_128';
  let presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  let slide = presentation.getSlideById(diceStackId);
  let pageElements = slide.getPageElements();

  // I modified below script.
  const obj = {"1": "dice 1", "2": "dice 2", "3": "dice 3", "4": "dice 4", "5": "dice 5", "6": "dice 6"};
  const pageElement = pageElements.filter(e => e.getTitle() == obj[showMe]);
  if (pageElement.length == 1) {
    pageElement[0].bringToFront();
  }
}
```

- In this modified script, `obj` is used for searching the page element with the title. For example, when `3` is given as `showMe`, the page element which has the title of `dice 3` is moved to the front.
- When the page elements with the same title are existing, the script is not run. Please be careful this.
- If you want to check other titles, please modify `obj`.

#### References:

- [getPageElements()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#getpageelements)
- [bringToFront()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/group#bringtofront)

Comment: Just found ArrangeStackingOrder v1.0.0 (October 10, 2018) library - you are all over this

Comment: "when a page element is moved to the front, the indexes are changed" #@&(*#&%()@^)*&)*^ This worked great. I was able to manually add my images, loop through and set title and position. Next I tried adding the images from drive. The following is the trick I needed: googlesystem.blogspot.com/2013/02/…

Comment: @L.Klein Thank you for replying. When I had published the library, there were no methods like `bringToFront()`. So I had proposed the workaround using Slides API. But, now, you can achieve it using the simple method.